# How to easily deploy Node.js using Netlify

Tags: node.js, deployment, netlify

I want to easily deploy Node.js using Netlify in react we can build our react app then we can deploy it but in case of node what is the procedure?

Comment: What research have you done? There are many hits for search terms taken right out of your question.

Comment: Found heroku to be the best fit for mern stack but for react its easy to deploy with netlify but have to research more.

Comment: You should share, in the Question with an [edit], what research you have done. Take the [tour] to see how SO is different than threaded forums. I literally found the start of an answer to you question with a web search copied from words in your question.